# can't change the name of submit button

Tags: jquery

I have a checkbox where I want it to change the name of the submit button, but it's not having it.

Here's the relevant code

```
$( document ).ready(function()
    {
        $('input[name=checkbox_htmlName]').change(function() {
                if(this.checked) {
                        confirm("I am checked");
                        // $(this).prop("checked", returnVal);
                        //change from edit to delete
                        // document.getElementById(submit_btn_id).name = 'Delete Selected Item';
                        $('input[name=submit_htmlName]').val = 'Delete Selected Item';
                } else {
                    confirm("I am NOT checked");
                    // document.getElementById(submit_btn_id).name = 'Edit Selected Item';
                    $('input[name=submit_htmlName]').val = 'Edit Selected Item';
                }
        });
    });
```

The button info is

```
<input type="submit" name='submit_htmlName' id='submit_btn_id' class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="change my name" alt="Edit Selected Item"/>
```

The code is in action at https://jsfiddle.net/mauricev/9py4vmco/1/

Answer (score 1):

`val` is a function in jquery

**https://api.jquery.com/val/**

```
$('input[name=checkbox_htmlName]').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    confirm("I am checked");
    $('input[name=submit_htmlName]').val('Delete Selected Item');
  } else {
    confirm("I am NOT checked");
    $('input[name=submit_htmlName]').val('Edit Selected Item');
  }
});
```

```js
$('input[name=checkbox_htmlName]').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    confirm("I am checked");
    $('input[name=submit_htmlName]').val('Delete Selected Item');
  } else {
    confirm("I am NOT checked");
    $('input[name=submit_htmlName]').val('Edit Selected Item');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="container">
  <form class="needs-validation" novalidate action="edit_gene_element.php" method="post">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9 mb-3">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="delete-checkbox" name='checkbox_htmlName' value='checkbox_htmlValue'>
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="delete-checkbox">Switch to delete mode</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9 mb-3">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
        <input type="submit" name='submit_htmlName' id='submit_btn_id' class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="change my name" alt="Edit Selected Item" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the below methods to achieve this.

Using .val() is used to set the value of every matched element

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($){
    $('input[name=checkbox_htmlName]').change(function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            $('input[name=submit_htmlName]').val('Delete Selected Item');
        } else {
            $('input[name=submit_htmlName]').val('Edit Selected Item');
        }
    });
});
```

Using .attr() you can modify the attribute value to the required values

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($){
    $('input[name=checkbox_htmlName]').change(function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            $('input[name=submit_htmlName]').attr('value','Delete Selected Item');
        } else {
            $('input[name=submit_htmlName]').attr('value','Edit Selected Item');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery: you can append value by using `val()` or you can do using attr:

```
$('input[name=submit_htmlName]').attr('value','Delete Selected Item')
```

```js
$( document ).ready(function(){
        $('input[name=checkbox_htmlName]').change(function() {
                if(this.checked) {
                        confirm("I am checked");
                        // $(this).prop("checked", returnVal);
                        //change from edit to delete
                        // document.getElementById(submit_btn_id).name = 'Delete Selected Item';
                        $('input[name=submit_htmlName]').val('Delete Selected Item');
                } else {
                    confirm("I am NOT checked");
                    // document.getElementById(submit_btn_id).name = 'Edit Selected Item';
                    $('input[name=submit_htmlName]').val('Edit Selected Item');
                }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="submit" name='submit_htmlName' id='submit_btn_id' class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="change my name" alt="Edit Selected Item"/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="delete-checkbox" name='checkbox_htmlName' value='checkbox_htmlValue'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `val()` as a function.

```
$('input[name=submit_htmlName]').val('Delete Selected Item');
$('input[name=submit_htmlName]').val('Edit Selected Item');
```